# numpy distutils specify intel fortran compiler in setup.py

Tags: python, numpy, setuptools, distutils

So, I have some fortran code that I can compile with f2py using ifort with this

```
f2py -c file.f90 -m module --fcompiler=intelem
```

Now I want to make it a package with a a setup.py, so how do I specify the intel fortran compiler option in the setup.py Extension option?

Comment: Just pass it via command line; the syntax is the same as with `f2py`, e.g. `python setup.py build_ext --fcompiler=intelem` etc.

Comment: @9769953 `extra_compile_args` will be passed to C compiler instead of `f2py`.

Comment: @9769953 your suggestion gives me this `unrecognized command line option ???--fcompiler=intelem???`

Comment: @hoefling so to change from gfortran to ifort I need to pass a parameter to the build process and then also change the `f90 flags` (optimization, parallelization etc.) specified in `setup.py`.  Can't this be just an one place process, i.e . can't I just specify the options in just one place instead of two?

Comment: Unfortunately, `numpy` defines `fcompiler` to be passed via command line to `build_ext`/`build_clib` and passing it via `f2py_options` breaks `f2py` because it defines own way of parsing command line args. Your only options are: 1. passing via command line; 2. persisting the option in `setup.cfg` to not to enter it each time and 3. overriding `numpy`'s `build_ext` and finalizing the option to `intelem` regardless what was passed. The third option will keep the complete configuration in `setup.py`, but IMO it's not worth the effort.

Comment: also I found if I use environment variable `export F90=ifort` then setup uses ifort compiler. And I can check the variable inside the `setup.py` inside the script to set proper compiler flags. So, I don't have to change the script manually while changing compiler.  Is this way of doing this okay? @hoefling